# SQL: Storing guids

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I now have a requirement that a column has to be added to a table that holds a unique ID (guid). This ID is used to match records in different tables and databases but there will be NO FK constraints. Would it be better to store the guid as a varchar(32) or as a uniqueidentifier type?

There will be joins done using this column but not on a regular basis. This ID is NOT a PK. I'm asking in terms of storage and performance.

Comment: As Jack has answered, store it as a `uniqueidentifier`. Make sure however that the clustered index of the table is not based on this field as it will cause performance problems with inserts.

Comment: it's going to be an arbitrary column, no need for clustered index.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If it's a GUID, store it as a `uniqueidentifier`

Comment: +1 Uniqueidentifier is supported very good by SQL Server. I can not imagine any reason to save a GUID not in a uniqueidentifier field.

Comment: Agreed.  If you know what it is, no need to store it as something else.

Comment: +1 Doing somethings else feels as logical as storing ints as strings

Comment: @Titan2782: a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` takes 16 bytes to store - a `VARCHAR(32)` needs 32 bytes for the data (which isn't really variable length at all), and it needs to store the actual length somewhere, plus since it's a variable length field (without really needing to be) that will add more overhead to SQL Server storage, too. So using `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` isn't only the "natural" choice (store a `GUID` as a `GUID`) - it's also the more "economical" in terms of disk space needed.