# How can I find out the different amount of space consumed by a nvarchar(128) and a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER?

Tags: sql-server

My application is storing a GUID UserId as a NVARCHAR(128). I was considering storing this as a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER. How can I find out the different amount of space in bytes that is consumed by each. In Oracle I seem to remember there was some way to do this though code. Does any similar way exist in SQL Server?

Comment: Sounds like it would be easier just to look in the manual at the storage requirements of each type.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL: Storing guids](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903261/sql-storing-guids)

Comment: NVARCHAR(128) uses (128*2) + 2 bytes and UNIQUEIDENTIFIER uses 16 bytes. Refer https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-data-types-reference/ for additional information.

Comment: @Bhasyakarulu - Are you saying then that it is 258 vs 16 ?  Would it not be the case that even though it is 128 if I put a GUID in there then it would occupy a lot less space.

Comment: Since GUID (assuming currently NVARCHAR(128) is having GUID in it) is of length 36 (36 *2) + 2 it will take 74 bytes, if you convert to GUID then it will take 16. It will be 74 Vs 16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UNIQUEIDENTIFIER is always 16 bytes (unless it is NULL and either the field is marked as SPARSE or the clustered index has compression enabled).

Assuming the NVARCHAR version is 36 characters (32 hex digits + 4 dashes), that is 72 bytes (or 0 if NULL or empty).

Most databases (all that I have ever encountered) only take up the actual space used for "var" types (VARCHAR,  NVARCHAR, and VARBINARY) and the full space for non-"var" types (CHAR, NCHAR, and BINARY).

Answer (score 0):

A guid in SQL Server is 16 bytes

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx

Comment: But how much space is occupied in bytes if I store that GUID in a nvarchar(128) ?